# How can I get how many physical frames and virtual pages are available in this system?

Tags: operating-system

Suppose the following properties are given:

- 32-bit virtual address
- 16-kbyte virtual page size
- 32-bit Page Table Entry
- 8-Gbyte physical memory

(that 1Gb = 230 bytes and 1 kb = 210 bytes)
Does this mean that the page table must have 2^20=1048576? And how can I calculate its physical frame and virtual page?

Answer (score 0):

The physical page size must match the virtual page size (16 KiB).

With 8 GiB of physical memory divided into 16 KiB pages; you'd end up with 524288 pages of physical RAM. However, the physical address space is also used things that aren't RAM (ROM, memory mapped devices, etc), and often some physical memory is "stolen" for other purposes (e.g. integrated graphics) and made inaccessible via. any normal physical addresses. With this in mind the correct answer is "the number of physical frames is unknowable, there isn't enough information".

If virtual addresses are 32-bit, then the virtual address space size is 4 GiB. With 4 GiB of virtual address space divided into 16 KiB pages you'd end up with 262144 virtual pages per virtual address space. However; there are an unknowable number of virtual address spaces (and an unknowable amount of each virtual address space will probably be used as "kernel space that is the same in all virtual address spaces"); so the correct answer is "the total number of virtual pages (for all virtual address spaces) is unknowable, there isn't enough information".